# Why only Chrome is white flashing between pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I know this topic was many times asked by developers and answered many times by high quality answers about how to optimize a page, optimize script run etc, and/or suggesting choosing less flashy background. However I think this is a new aspect.

Of course my web page is not perfectly optimized but still here is the fact: When testing my pages this very user unfriendly blank page flashing (whatever color it is) only experienced in Chrome. When testing in FF and IE there is no way to see any blank page between page renderings.

- One may think: There are some conditional logic, detecting Chrome in my code/css. Well there is no.
- Also, the pages actually are loading equal speed or faster in Chrome...
- Please note: This rendering difference behavior of Chrome can be easily experienced in many outer world web site, not only in mine.

I am hoping there must be a way to force Chrome to behave way most user friendly mode just like other browsers. Any idea or experience to share?

To demonstrate:

1. Goto [google](http://www.google.com), use Chrome
2. Type to search 'qwe'
3. After the page rendered press Ctrl+F5. You should see an annoying white flash
4. Goto [google](http://www.google.com), use FF
5. Type to search 'qwe'
6. After the page rendered press Ctrl+F5. There is no way to see any flash. The page still reloading, completely see the status bar, or use a http debugger like Fiddler for proof.

If anyone want a video of this, please leave a comment.

Comment: You could try this: http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d

Comment: White flashing? Do you mean *FOUC*? The problem is not Chrome. Run your pages from the other side of the planet or from a 90's PC with 56k, you'll have this problem everywhere.

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur: I've tried, (applied, then checked in Chrome dev tools if the style is actually applied (yes)) but unfortunately still same blank flashes.

Comment: Do you have a testcase for this, so we can see if on our own machines?

Comment: @RedBreast I've thought my aspect is clear enough sorry if it is not understandable/acceptable: Other browsers with the _very_ same context does not do this at all, while Chrome does in many web sites. I like Chrome too, that's my everyday browser and dev browser.

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur: Good point I am editing my answer to give a demonstration what I am talking about.

Comment: @RedBreast: ...and one more thing: Of course I've experienced this in the 90's and did not asked why... I am a patient man, so I've waited a quarter century so I am asking now, in 2015, why? :-)

Comment: Firefox does not remove the page until he has enough to show on the other page. It looks like there is no flash in firefox because FF has hidden it. And seriously... Chrome? Use a real browser please :p

Comment: CTRL+F5 is force clear cache.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: Besides of personal preferences you are right. That was I tried to first in my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555703/how-to-temporary-suspend-browser-rendering-then-resume-for-the-whole-page question, but it seems no one interested in it...

Comment: On my machine, Chrome also flashes horribly when you resize the window, not only when you do Ctrl+F5. One of the reasons I like SeaMonkey better. I mean IceWeasel, sorry.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Yes, so simulate to navigate a page what must be loaded in steps. Let's focus on that the white flash is not inevitable (see FF)

Comment: @g.pickardou there are way too many variables. FF and Chrome are completely different in the way they process things.

Comment: This is a known chrome issue. Don't waste your time debugging, it's not your code. view https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470669

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how Chromes `load-parse-render-etc` process works. It starts rendering as soon as possible, even when actually no content is there to display. So you see the white screen.

It will be clear after two examples.

### 1

---

*`html`*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>
    <h4>Header</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

When parser meets the remote `script`, it stops HTML parsing until the script is loaded and evaluated. But in a meanwhile engine tries to render what it already has. It has nothing, so you see a white page, and after some time, when a script is ready, it continues with HTML parsing and rendering, so you see the text. Consider this loading timeline and notice the 2 Paint events:

[image: Load Process]

### 2

---

*`html`*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function showTimespan() {
            var h4 = document.createElement('h4');
            h4.textContent = Date.now();
            document.body.appendChild(h4);
        }
        showTimespan();
    </script>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>
    <script>
        showTimespan();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when parser stops at loading of the remote script, it has already content to show, which was generated in previous `script` tag. *Instead of the `script`, there could be any other `html` content* And once again, when the remote script is loaded and evaluated, engine continues with the rest content, and renders it. The timeline here would be the same.

Now, if you open the sample in Firefox you would see the both `<h4>` rendered at once. Firefox just delays the first render **without clearing** the page. And in the timeline you would see only one `Paint` event.

[image]

*I was using here the `jQuery` only for the network-load purpose, as I needed some not small remote library, so that you hopefully notice the renders with naked-eye.*

*I was using script generated content in the second example, so that you notice when actually Firefox renders.*

But what approach is better, is difficult to say. Personally I like, when it actually shows what it has, as I see then the real progress.